# CompletableFuture doesn't work if it saved to variable

Tags: java, future, completable-future

Why does it not work when I save the future to variable before configuration steps?

```
@Test
void simple() {
    CompletableFuture<String> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::throwException)
            .exceptionally(throwable -> HANDLED);
    assertEquals(HANDLED, future.join());
}

@Test
void withVar() {
    CompletableFuture<String> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::throwException);
    future.exceptionally(throwable -> HANDLED);
    assertEquals(HANDLED, future.join());
}

private String throwException() {
    if (true) {
        throw new RuntimeException(FAIL);
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

`simple()` is fine, but `withVar()` doesn't work:

```
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: FAIL

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:314)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:319)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1702)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1692)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)`
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: FAIL
    at ru.dionisis.resttest.ComplitableFutureTest.throwException(ComplitableFutureTest.java:35)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
    ... 6 more`
```

A similar problem was with `RestTemplateBuilder`, when I wanted make otional init one field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the JavaDoc for `exceptionally`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#exceptionally-java.util.function.Function-): "*Returns a **new** CompletableFuture*...". It does not mutate the CompleteableFuture that it's called upon.

You are creating a new CompleteableFuture with new behaviour and then throwing that away, then `join`ing on the original CompleteableFuture which does not have that behaviour.

It's like saying that `String::toUpperCase` doesn't work in this example. It *does* work, but the result is thrown away.

```
String foo = "bar";
foo.toUpperCase();
assertEquals("BAR", foo);
```